# Merge multiple png images with transparency in node.js

Tags: node.js, png, graphicsmagick

I use this code to merge multiple images to one, but the transparency is gone in the result file. The background is solid black.

```
gm.in('convert').in('-size', '200x100')
.in('xc:transparent')
.in('-page', '+0+0').in('image1.png')
.in('-page', '+100+0').in('image1.png')
.in('-flatten')
.write('result.png', function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
})
```

I also tried:

```
.in('background', 'transparent')
```

and

```
.in('background', 'black')
.in('transparency', 'black')
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
gm.in('convert').in('-size', '200x100')
  .in('-page', '+0+0').in('image1.png')
  .in('-page', '+100+0').in('image1.png')
  .in('-background', 'none')
  .write('result.png', function (err) {
     if (err) console.log(err);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/FAQ.html#how-can-i-add-a-matte-layer-to-my-image

You'll need to use the composite command.

```
gm.prototype.compose = function(operator) {
   this.command('composite'); // need to use composite over the node gm default convert
   return this.out("-compose", operator);
};


gm....
.compose('CopyOpacity').
```

Comment: In my case **gm** is the module gm, which I installed via npm: gm = require('gm'). The error is TypeError: Object #<gm> has no method 'command'. Are you using a different library?

Comment: Yes, and the prototype override should let you use 'composite' instead of the default.

Comment: I didn't get it to work and decided to use Imagemagic. It works for me out of the box. Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

For those confused by this discussion.  GM has continued development but under a fork on github.  The originator has failed to keep the npm up to date.  Just fork the latest fork directly into node_modules.

Comment: Do you have a link to the fork?